# "SqlException was unhandled" error while trying to run login in C# form

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(global::Database_test.Properties.Settings.Default.Database1ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Login where username='" + textBox5.Text + "' and Password = '" + textBox6.Text + "'conn");
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    conn.Open();

    SqlDataReader re = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (re.Read())
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Login Sucessful");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Login Failed");
    }

}
```

Comment: What exception are you getting? Btw, I would recommend using SqlStatements, so you can avoid sql injection related problems

Comment: So what was the exception? You've said that there *is* one, but given no details about what it is. (And yes, you should definitely use parameterized SQL...)

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Login where username='" + textBox5.Text + "' and Password = '" + textBox6.Text + "'conn");
```

to this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Login where username='" + textBox5.Text + "' and Password = '" + textBox6.Text + "'", conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before any suggestion you may send us your InnerException description or you may need to provide more information, as this exception is general one. However following are some tips that I suggest you to take look at:

1. Take care of "conn" at the end of teh following line:

   ```
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Login where username='" + textBox5.Text + "' and Password = '" + textBox6.Text + "'conn");
   ```

"conn" should be passed as SqlCommand's second parameter:

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Login where username='" + textBox5.Text + "' and Password = '" + textBox6.Text + "'",conn);
```

2.Take care of using onn.Open(); expression. I always put it in following block:

```
if(conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
   conn.Open();
```

find more about ConnectionState enumeration [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.connectionstate(v=vs.110).aspx)